# Find and replace using regular expressions - remove double spaces between letters only

Tags: regex, replace, atom-editor

Trying to do this in the Atom editor (1.39.1 x64, uBuntu 18.04), though assume this applies to other text editors using regular expressions.

Say we have this text:

`This  text has some  double-spaces.  Lets try  to remove them.
    But not  after a   full-stop or if three or  more spaces.`

Which we would like to change to:

`This text has some double-spaces.  Lets try to remove them.
    But not after a   full-stop or if three or more spaces.`

Using Find with `Regex` enabled (`.*`), all occurrences are correctly found using: `[a-zA-Z]  [a-zA-Z]`. But what goes in the `Replace` row to enforce the logic:

```
1st letter, single space, 2nd letter?
```

Comment: why spaces after `a` is still intact ?

Comment: I believe you can look for two spaces not preceded by a period: `(?<!\.)\s{2}(?=[^\s]` Anything more than two spaces and you don't want to replace it, a single space doesn't need to be replaced, and two spaces should only be replaced if they don't follow a period. EDIT: Edited to add a positive lookahead since the two spaces can't be followed by another space.

Comment: @CodeManiac: Because there are three spaces after `a` and before `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
([a-z])\s{2}([a-z])
```

and replace by `$1 $2`

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/LqYbmf/1/)

If your editor supports lookarounds you can use

```
(?<=[a-z])\s{2}(?=[a-z])
```

Replace by single space character

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/ertWVp/2/)

Note:- don't forget to use `i` flag for case insensitivity or just change the character class to `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: This works in Atom 1.39.1...thanks! At a guess, what is happening is that the first `([a-z])` part is being saved as temporary environment variable `$1` which allows me to use it in the `Replace` part.

Comment: @AlainD yes, this `()`is called capture group in regex, which later can be back referenced if needed, if you editor supports lookarounds than you don't need these captures groups